# How to use a variable in a cfquery?

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

I use `#variable.user#` to show the active user on a webpage I want to use that user to look up in a table and find their work location so I can create a custom few for each work location. How can I use that variable in a query to find their location in the table?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should provide examples of the code you have tried and explain how that code is not giving you the desired results. Include any error messages you may be getting. See this reference [ask]

Comment: Take a look at `<cfqueryparam>` if you are using CFML or `cfaddparam` if your are using cfscript.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question seems clear to me. Not sure why ppl have voted to close with "Needs details or clarity". How else would you word this question?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this two ways:

1. Reference the variable via #myVar#. If it is a string, put single quotes around it. **I do not recommend doing it this way**.

EX:

```
<cfquery name="somequery" datasource="somedb">
SELECT
    sometable.somecolumn
FROM
    sometable
WHERE
    sometable.somecolumn = '#myVar#'
</cfquery>
```

2. Using cfqueryparams to verify/force a datatype and reference that variable. This prevents SQL injection and other SQL based errors if you have specific constraints. **I recommmend doing it this way**. See [cfqueryparam tag abobe documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html).

EX:

```
<cfquery name="somequery" datasource="somedb">
SELECT
    sometable.somecolumn
FROM
    sometable
WHERE
    sometable.somecolumn = <cfqueryparam cfsqlype="varchar" value="#myVar#">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I cannot emphasise strongly enough that the first approach should not be used. One should not mung data values into the SQL statement like that; it's poor separation of concerns (which you allude to with yer SQL injection comment). One should always pass data values as parameters, as per the second example (except given it's 2022 now, I'd probably use `queryExecute`, not `<cfquery>`.